# IE9: hasOwnProperty trick does not work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype, hasownproperty

It's well documented that native DOM elements in IE do not contain the hasOwnProperty() method. There are a couple of solutions to this; the most elegant of which involves accessing the hasOwnProperty() method directly in Object.prototype, like so:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(element, name);
```

It seems to me that this no longer works in IE9. Can someone explain? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHRZs/) illustrating this.

Using IE9 in Standards mode with Compatibility Mode turned off, the alert displays:

```
sessionStorage is supported: false
localStorage is supported: false
```

However, after turning the Compatibility or Quirks Mode on (or using the Developer Tools to render the page using the IE8 and IE7 engines) the alert displays:

```
sessionStorage is supported: true
localStorage is supported: true
```

Is there something else at work here, or is this workaround for hasOwnProperty no longer usable?

Comment: I don't see anything in the [EcmaScript DOM bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/ecma-script-binding.html) which says they should be own properties and not getters defined on a prototype.  Why do you care whether they are own properties?  Why does `'undefined' !== typeof element.sessionStorage` not suffice?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410104.aspx: seems IE9 has `hasOwnProperty` now.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Generally that construct isn't recommended because a it passes for members that exist but have an assigned "undefined" value. Your point concerning what the standard has to say (or rather, doesn't have to say) about the bindings is a good one, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because those properties are stored in the prototype chain of `window` instead of directly on the object.

If you use `in`, it'll search the prototype chain for you, and give you `true` in `IE9`.

```
var isSessionStorageSupported = "sessionStorage" in window; // true
var isLocalStorageSupported = "localStorage" in window;     // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fHRZs/2/

So `.hasOwnProperty()` is giving the correct result.

Comment: True. `hasOwnProperty` explicitly does not check the prototype chain, which is why it's so useful.

Comment: @tjameson: Yes, useful on those occasions where you don't want to include prototyped properties. Not so useful when you do.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I assumed since the other major browsers implement the most commonly used members associated with the window object, as (non-inherited) members, that IE would be similar. Silly me. However, my testing suggests that the migration of the mentioned members (and more that I have not listed) to the prototype chain was carried out for IE9+. I suppose you wouldn't happen to know why?

Comment: @Kevin: I could only guess that they do it so that if that property is added directly to `window` by some developer, it wouldn't overwrite the native one. Firefox does the same thing with those properties.